# Removing other OBJECTs from an array of OBJECTs (NPM Twit)

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, twitter

I'm working the NPM "twit" for Twitter,
I'm trying to filter out all the other mentions in a tweet from `tweet.text` except the first mention (reply-to)

`tweet.entities.user_mentions` shows ALL mentions
`tweet.text` can contain both all mentions and regular message.

`tweet.entities.user_mentions` outputs like `user_mentions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ]`

Any suggestions to removing every other mention besides the first? from `tweet.text` *IF* it contains mentions

```js
tweet.entities.user_mentions.map((user) => user.screen_name)
```

DATA Example

```yaml
{
  created_at: 'Fri Jun 11 16:14:05 +0000 2021',
  id: redacted,
  id_str: 'redacted',
  text: '@redacted1 @redacted2 @redacted3 @redacted4 @redacted 5 bruh im busy working on my latest project kek',
  display_text_range: [ 54, 99 ],
  source: '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>',
  truncated: false,
  in_reply_to_status_id: redacted,
  in_reply_to_status_id_str: 'redacted',
  in_reply_to_user_id: redacted,
  in_reply_to_user_id_str: 'redacted',
  in_reply_to_screen_name: 'redacted1',
  user: {
    id: redacted,
    id_str: 'redacted',
    name: '᲼',
    screen_name: 'RudimentalHack',
    location: null,
    url: '',
    description: '',
    translator_type: 'none',
    protected: false,
    verified: false,
    followers_count: 4,
    friends_count: 25,
    listed_count: 0,
    favourites_count: 3,
    statuses_count: 88,
    created_at: 'Sat Mar 13 02:58:05 +0000 2021',
    utc_offset: null,
    time_zone: null,
    geo_enabled: false,
    lang: null,
    contributors_enabled: false,
    is_translator: false,
    profile_background_color: 'F5F8FA',
    profile_background_image_url: '',
    profile_background_image_url_https: '',
    profile_background_tile: false,
    profile_link_color: '1DA1F2',
    profile_sidebar_border_color: 'C0DEED',
    profile_sidebar_fill_color: 'DDEEF6',
    profile_text_color: '333333',
    profile_use_background_image: true,
    profile_image_url: 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1396266004284575753/dzhuS7To_normal.png',
    profile_image_url_https: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1396266004284575753/dzhuS7To_normal.png',
    default_profile: true,
    default_profile_image: false,
    following: null,
    follow_request_sent: null,
    notifications: null,
    withheld_in_countries: []
  },
  geo: null,
  coordinates: null,
  place: null,
  contributors: null,
  is_quote_status: false,
  quote_count: 0,
  reply_count: 0,
  retweet_count: 0,
  favorite_count: 0,
  entities: {
    hashtags: [],
    urls: [],
    user_mentions: [ [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object], [Object] ],
    symbols: []
  },
  favorited: false,
  retweeted: false,
  filter_level: 'low',
  lang: 'en',
  timestamp_ms: '1623428045633'
}
```

Comment: it's easier to help if you show a sample of your data, describe your expected output and show what attempt you made at solving it (in code)

Comment: @Kinglish I've updated it so it's better :)

Comment: to clarify, you want to get the same object back - except make `user_mentions` a single object (rather than an array of multiple objects) and the `text` to only have one (first) `@redacted`?

Comment: @Kinglish essentially yes.

Comment: So say text only returns the first `@redacted1` then the following message after it so like
`@redacted1 bruh im busy working on my latest project kek`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple `map()` that iterates through the object. The `.text` is modified using `reduce()` and the `.user_mentions` with `splice()`. Code is commented below.

```js
const twit = {
  created_at: 'Fri Jun 11 16:14:05 +0000 2021',
  id: 'redacted',
  id_str: 'redacted',
  text: '@redacted1 @redacted2 @redacted3 @redacted4 @redacted 5 bruh im busy working on my latest project kek',
  display_text_range: [54, 99],
  source: '<a href="https://mobile.twitter.com" rel="nofollow">Twitter Web App</a>',
  truncated: false,
  in_reply_to_status_id: 'redacted',
  in_reply_to_status_id_str: 'redacted',
  in_reply_to_user_id: 'redacted',
  in_reply_to_user_id_str: 'redacted',
  in_reply_to_screen_name: 'redacted1',
  user: {
    id: 'redacted',
    id_str: 'redacted',
    name: '᲼',
    screen_name: 'RudimentalHack',
    location: null,
    url: '',
    description: '',
    translator_type: 'none',
    protected: false,
    verified: false,
    followers_count: 4,
    friends_count: 25,
    listed_count: 0,
    favourites_count: 3,
    statuses_count: 88,
    created_at: 'Sat Mar 13 02:58:05 +0000 2021',
    utc_offset: null,
    time_zone: null,
    geo_enabled: false,
    lang: null,
    contributors_enabled: false,
    is_translator: false,
    profile_background_color: 'F5F8FA',
    profile_background_image_url: '',
    profile_background_image_url_https: '',
    profile_background_tile: false,
    profile_link_color: '1DA1F2',
    profile_sidebar_border_color: 'C0DEED',
    profile_sidebar_fill_color: 'DDEEF6',
    profile_text_color: '333333',
    profile_use_background_image: true,
    profile_image_url: 'http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1396266004284575753/dzhuS7To_normal.png',
    profile_image_url_https: 'https://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1396266004284575753/dzhuS7To_normal.png',
    default_profile: true,
    default_profile_image: false,
    following: null,
    follow_request_sent: null,
    notifications: null,
    withheld_in_countries: []
  },
  geo: null,
  coordinates: null,
  place: null,
  contributors: null,
  is_quote_status: false,
  quote_count: 0,
  reply_count: 0,
  retweet_count: 0,
  favorite_count: 0,
  entities: {
    hashtags: [],
    urls: [],
    user_mentions: [{
      mention: 'hello'
    }, {
      mention: 'hello2'
    }, {
      mention: 'hello3'
    }, {
      mention: 'hello4'
    }, {
      mention: 'hello5'
    }],
    symbols: []
  },
  favorited: false,
  retweeted: false,
  filter_level: 'low',
  lang: 'en',
  timestamp_ms: '1623428045633'
}

// iterate twit as if it was an array 
const ntwit = [twit].map(el => {
  // fix the el.text by splitting and then testing our accumlating reduce array to see if it has an instance of @something
  el.text = el.text.split(" ").reduce((b, a) => {
    if (!a.includes('@') || !b.some(e => /\@(.)/g.test(e))) b.push(a)
    return b;
  }, []).join(" ");
  // simple splice using the array length as an argument
  el.entities.user_mentions.splice(1)
  return el
})[0]; // we faked it as an array, now just extract it.

console.log(ntwit);
```

Comment: I will test this out later today, I'll let you know when I do @Kinglish

Comment: Unable to test it currently, due to IRL issues arising.
But the second I get a minute to myself I will test :)